# How I can find if there was a success or error in reading file content using PHP

Tags: php

I wrote a PHP code like this

```
$site="http://www.google.com";
$content = file_get_content($site);
echo $content;
```

How I can find if there was a success or error in reading file content. Can we add a event listener like onSuccess and onError?

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. :-) [After doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `file_get_content()` is similar to `file()`, except that `file_get_contents()` returns the file in a string, starting at the specified offset up to maxlen bytes. On failure, `file_get_contents()` will return `FALSE`. So you could check for `if not false` condition. I suggest you to google . It helps :)

More information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)